# fetch error message reason get addrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, fetch

I'm making a slack clone with socket.io and node with a mongodb cluster. everything worked fine this weekend until today when i opened the project and noticed a message I've never seen before:

(node:31352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to http://localhost:5000/chat failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at ClientRequest. (/Users/philiplagergrenydehed/git/slack-clone/slack-clone/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1455:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:219:5)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:420:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:219:5)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:84:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
(node:31352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)

What does this mean and how do i fix it?

This is my fetch but I cannot see anything wrong with it.

```
router.post('/new', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body)

  const messageObject = {
    channelID: '437469384738473894',
    name: req.body.name,
    time: req.body.time,
    text: req.body.message
  }
  const option = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(messageObject)
  };

  try{

  fetch('http://localhost:5000/chat', option)
  .then(response => {
    response.json()

    .then(function(data){

      response.send(data)
    });
  });
} catch{
  res.send("error")
}
})
```

I'm stuck and I really need your help!!

Comment: your /etc/hosts file is broken - check it. It should contain 127.0.0.1 localhost . probably you added something to it in a batch mode while last line did not have carriage return.

Comment: yeah i got it yesterday after few hours of research!! thank you anyways!